# Get suggestions *inside* the bracket in "\begin{ }" TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

If I start writing `\begin{`, the auto-complete suggestions comes up with this:

[image]

Then I press <kbd>enter</kbd> and get to this:

[image]

What want to is to get suggestion for environments when I start typing. e.g.

[image]

I would like TexStudio to suggest e.g. 'equation' so that I don't have to write it myself. Is this possible?

Comment: Two possibilities: either continue typing, e.g. with `\begin{equ` will be the only element left in the list and you can select it with enter or scroll down the list you get in your picture above until you see `equation`

Comment: To narrow down the list you could also try to use the "most used" suggestions instead of the "typical" ones

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  But i would like exactly what i describe above.

Comment: How about: start to write `\beg`, use `tab` instead of `enter` to autocomplete to `\begin{` then continue writing `eq` until equation is the first entry in the autocomplete list?

Comment: @samcarter Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Can you make it an answer, so I can tag it?

Comment: I converted my comment into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start typing `\beg` ...

[image]

... you can use `tab` to complete it to `\begin{` without closing the list of auto-complete suggestions.

[image]

You can now simply continue to type `equ` until your desired environment is selected in the list of suggestions...

[image]

...and then use `enter` to select it.

Answer (score 3):

You can press `ctrl`+`space` to get suggestions after you started typing.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to match your question.
[image]